# Promise function unable to access parent variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I am unfamiliar with the use of promises in angularjs and I am currently facing difficulties in generating certain output. I am trying to use for loops to generate an array of sentences, with each sentence going by "levelName: groupName - description".

I have a factory called "prodFactory" which uses $http.get to obtain the levelName, groupName and description by methods getLevelNames(), getGroupNames(levelName) and getGroupData(groupName). From my source file, I have an array of 3 levelNames, each of which are associated to an array of 2 groupNames. When running the code below, I tried logging the values and I got the following results:

i = 229, j = 2, data1 = my defined level names, data2 = my defined group names.

Although I was able to get my level and group names, as the values of i and j are off from what are defined by the for loops, I was getting the results of "undefined: undefined - description".

Are there anyways to get the correct output? Thanks!

### Code snippet

```
prodFactory.getLevelNames().then(function(data1){
            var suggestions = [];
            $scope.data1 = data1;
            for(i=0; i<data1.length; i++){
                prodFactory.getGroupNames(data1[i]).then(function(data2){
                    $scope.data2 = data2;
                    for(j=0; j<data2.length; j++){
                        prodFactory.getGroupData(data2[j]).then(function(data3){
                                $scope.data3 = data3;
                                for(k=0; k<data3[0].length; k++){
                                    console.log(i);
                                    console.log(j);
                                    console.log(data1);
                                    console.log(data2);
                                    suggestions.push($scope.data1[i]+": "
                                    +$scope.data2[j]+" - "+$scope.data3[0][k]);
                                };
                            });
                };
                });
        };
        $scope.getSuggestions = suggestions;
        console.log($scope.getSuggestions);
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last `console.log` in your code will execute before any of the HTTP requests will finish. That's because promises are always asynchronous.

Creating promises in loops makes it harder to process results later. You will need `$q.all` and `$q.spread` or some `Array` to add results into. Additionally making lots of HTTP requests will not be performant. You should strive to limit the number of requests at all times.

I would suggest to make methods that return results for all levels, groups and so on.

```
prodFactory.getLevelNames().then(function(data1){
  prodFactory.getGroupNames(data1).then(function(data2){
    prodFactory.getGroupData(data2).then(function(data3){
      $scope.suggestions = makeSuggestions(data1, data2, data3)
      console.log($scope.suggestions);
    });
  });
};
```

And please don't make a variable called `getSuggestions`. It looks like it's a method/function not a variable.

Comment: I think you misunderstand promises. You should try to avoid nesting them like callbacks. Instead flatten then chain if they are dependant. If there not use $q.all. So in this instance you could do `prodFactory.getLevelNames().then(prodFactory.getGroupNames).then(prodFactory.getGroupData).then(data2 => console.log(data2);`

Comment: @ste2425 You're solution is even better but flattening the chain is not required so i skipped that part.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use the nested promises**

because the order of execution is unpredictable.

Comment: ES6 promise semantics were chosen to be deterministic and predictable. They might not be obvious in all cases, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding of closure. So maybe you could take a look at [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Also I would suggest you to read [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

One thing that we can always try is to simplify the problem. In this case, we could try two levels of the problem first: we can try only getLevelNames(), getGroupNames(levelName) first.

To solve the two level problem, I would probably try:

```
prodFactory.getLevelNames()
.then(function(levelNames) {
    var suggestions = [];
    $scope.levelNames = levelNames;
    for(var i=0; i < levelNames.length; i++){ 
        // [IIFE][2]
        (function () {
            var index = i; 
            prodFactory.getGroupNames(levelNames[index])
            .then(function(groupNames) {
                $scope.groupNames[index] = groupNames;
                console.log(index);
                for (var j = 0; j < groupNames.length; ++j) {
                    suggestions.push($scope.levelNames[index]+": "
                                +$scope.groupNames[index][j]");
                }
            });
        })();
    }
    $scope.getSuggestions = suggestions;
    console.log($scope.getSuggestions);
});
```